# How can i update different rows with different values using single SQL update query on SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL developer and want to update different rows with different vlues using one unique ID and different rows id For example as mentioned below :

- **update repayment_schedule set fromdate ='03-SEP-22',
  duedate='03-OCT-22' where loan_id in '22' AND installment in '2'**

  **update m_loan_repayment_schedule set fromdate ='03-OCT-22',
  duedate='03-NOV-22' where loan_id in '22' AND installment in '3'**

  **update repayment_schedule set fromdate ='03-NOV-22',
  duedate='03-DEC-22' where loan_id in '22' AND installment in '4'**

Here Loan_id is only unique value in all rows .

How can i use only single query to update the rows with different values.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO repayment_schedule dst
USING (
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-03' AS fromdate, DATE '2022-10-03' AS todate, 22 AS loan_id, 2 AS installment FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-10-03', DATE '2022-11-03', 22, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-11-03', DATE '2022-12-03', 22, 4 FROM DUAL
) src
ON (dst.loan_id = src.loan_id AND dst.installment = src.installment)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET fromdate = src.fromdate,
      todate   = src.todate;
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE repayment_schedule (fromdate, todate, loan_id, installment) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-08-03', DATE '2022-09-03', 22, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;
```

After the `MERGE`, the table will contain:

> | FROMDATE | TODATE | LOAN_ID | INSTALLMENT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-08-03 00:00:00 | 2022-09-03 00:00:00 | 22 | 1 |
> | 2022-09-03 00:00:00 | 2022-10-03 00:00:00 | 22 | 2 |
> | 2022-10-03 00:00:00 | 2022-11-03 00:00:00 | 22 | 3 |
> | 2022-11-03 00:00:00 | 2022-12-03 00:00:00 | 22 | 4 |

---

However, for your specific situation where you appear to only be incrementing the months, you could calculate the values rather than hard-coding them:

```sql
UPDATE repayment_schedule
SET   fromdate = ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-08-03', installment - 1),
      todate   = ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-08-03', installment)
WHERE loan_id = 22
AND   installment BETWEEN 2 AND 4;
```

Which gives the same output as above.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2e6cbf55c1842650171ef5322a167f67)*

Comment: UPDATE repayment_schedule SET fromdate = ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-08-03', installment - 1), todate = ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-08-03', installment) WHERE loan_id = 22 AND installment BETWEEN 2 AND 4; 

The above query is giving output as required. If i want to add "installment BETWEEN 1 AND 12" but the "FROMDATE" in installment 1 should remain same as it is, but "DUEDATE " Should be changed in INSTALLMENT 1 and rest all INSTALLMENT BETWEEN 2 and 12 should be updated as in above query. THEN?